# Getting error in attach AdventuresWorks database in SQL Server (Using window 7)

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-7

I am newbie in Sql Server.I am trying to attach AdventureWorks database with Sql Server 2008(Window 7).following Error -

[image]

Can anyone tell me that how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to attach AdventureWorksDB.msi. First run this msi file, it will extract its contents somewhere. Then you will need to attach a file with extension .mdf.

Comment: No you don't. The installer attaches the multiple databases for you.

Comment: Thanks Sh_Kamalh..I have attahced..first I have extracted it and then attached it. It is working fine now..:)

Answer (score 1):

This is the installer package (msi). You must run it from explorer firstly.